NextJS 14: How to properly manage datas
I'm trying to redo a project I've already done with React and Express (classic SPA), but using NextJS 14 and RSC.
I only knew NextJS by name, but I wanted to try out the RSC that React brings to the fore.
But I'm struggling with data management. With SPA, it was simple: you have access to a state (useState / Redux).
With NextJS, on the other hand, there's no Store, and having a State too high up in the components will make all the Children (Client Side).
Which brings me to my two questions.

What do I do if I want a form divided over several pages? What's the best way of doing this, while retaining the advantages of RSC?

How can I have an AppBar with buttons that only appear when you're logged in?


